# Allocating memory for a char pointer that is part of a struct

Tags: c, memory-management

im trying to read in a word from a user, then dynamically allocate memory for the word and store it in a struct array that contains a char *.  i keep getting a  implicit declaration of function âstrlenâ so i know im going wrong somewhere.

```
struct unit
{
  char class_code[4];
  char *name;
};

char buffer[101];
struct unit units[1000];

scanf("%s", buffer);

units[0].name = (char *) malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
strcpy(units[0].name, buffer);
```

Comment: I assume that should be `struct unit`, not `struct class`.

Comment: @Ken, it's perfectly legal in C.

Comment: @Earlz - The fact that it is legal C is totally irrelevant. He is declaring a structure with tag "class" - which is never used - but using a structure with tag "unit" which is not declared anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

`Implicit declaration of function 'strlen'` means that you forgot to `#include` the header that declares it, in this case `<string.h>`

That's the only error I see in your code.

Comment: thank you, i knew it would something like that but couldnt think of what it was.  im still new to this so i make heaps of stupid mistakes

Answer (score 4):

Besides the missing header, `string.h`, you can replace your malloc+strcpy by strdup.

```
units[0].name = strdup(buffer);
```

Comment: jweyrich: Does strdup() allocate memory to char*? So u can do strcpy(units[0].name, "123") and then free(units[0].name) when done? Is this ANSI C?

Comment: Cool, I ll use it when I can :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are doing:

```
#include <string.h>
```

to include the strlen() function declaration.

Also, you should really be using strnlen() and strncpy() to prevent bugs.

Comment: There's no bug here. He's allocating enough memory for the string, based on knowing the contents of the string. That's perfectly safe use of `strcpy`. The use of `strlen` is also fine, so long as `scanf` doesn't overflow `buffer`. He might want to add a field length on the `%s` to ensure that.